# Flip associative array and store new values in subarrays to prevent losing duplicated values

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, merging-data, array-flip

I have a flat associative array which may contain duplicate values.

```
Array (
    [for-juniors] => product_category 
    [for-men] => product_category
    [coats] => product_category
    [for-women] => product_category
    [7-diamonds] => brand
)
```

I need to restructure the data to store the original values as new keys and the original keys pushed into subarrays associated with the new keys.

```
array(
    'product_category' => array(
        'for-juniors',
        'for-men',
        'coats',
        'for-women'
    ),
    'brand' => array(
        '7-diamonds'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$grouped = array();
foreach ($input as $choice => $group) {
    $grouped[$group][] = $choice;
}

var_dump($grouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because within a `foreach()` loop, the values are declared BEFORE the keys, [you can actually populate the new data structure with a body-less `foreach()` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71030746/2943403).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5ADBK))

```
$array = [
    'for-juniors' => 'product_category',
    'for-men' => 'product_category',
    'coats' => 'product_category',
    'for-women' => 'product_category',
    '7-diamonds' => 'brand'
];

$grouped = [];
foreach ($array as $grouped[$group][] => $group);
var_export($grouped);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'product_category' => 
  array (
    0 => 'for-juniors',
    1 => 'for-men',
    2 => 'coats',
    3 => 'for-women',
  ),
  'brand' => 
  array (
    0 => '7-diamonds',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This'll do:

```php
function array_flip_safe(array $array) : array
{
    return array_reduce(array_keys($array), function ($carry, $key) use (&$array) {
        $carry[$array[$key]] ??= []; // PHP 7.0 - ^7.3: $carry[$array[$key]] = $carry[$array[$key]] ?? [];
        $carry[$array[$key]][] = $key;
        return $carry;
    }, []);
}
```

The callback creates an empty array if the array doesn't already exist. Then it appends current iteration's `$key` (`$value` of `array_keys($array)`) to that array.

Here's an example for better understanding:

```php
$businessHours = [
    'mo' => '13:00 - 16:00',
    'tu' => '8:00 - 12:00',
    'we' => '13:00 - 16:00',
    'th' => '8:00 - 12:00',
    'fr' => '13:00 - 16:00',
    'sa' => '',
    'su' => '',
];

$flipped = array_flip_safe($businessHours);
```

`ray($flipped);` (or `var_dump`, `var_export`, etc.) outputs:

```
array:3 [▼
  "13:00 - 16:00" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "mo"
    1 => "we"
    2 => "fr"
  ]
  "8:00 - 12:00" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "tu"
    1 => "th"
  ]
  "" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "sa"
    1 => "su"
  ]
]
```

Note that the order of inner arrays' values is the same as the order of original array's keys.