# PHP defined function to Flip array keys and values without grouping

Tags: php

Is there any predefined function in any version of PHPs which could do this:

I have this array:

```
$arr = array(
    2 => 'John',
    21 => 'John',
    32 => 'Joe',
    42 => 'John',
    23 => 'Joe',
    62 => 'John',
    25 => 'Joe',
    );
```

I expect this result:

```
array(
    'John' => array(2, 21, 42, 62),
    'Joe' => array(32, 23, 25),
);
```

**array_flip** doesn't do what I want.

**Note:** I can write a custom code to do that and it's easy. My question is if there is a function in PHP can do it?

**Last update:** I think the answer should be **NO**

Comment: There's nothing do do that with a predefined function, but plenty of array functions that you can use with a custom callback.

Comment: Tried searching in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12425481/5447994)?

Answer (score 6):

This is solved quite simply with a foreach loop

```
$flipped = [];
foreach($arr AS $key => $value) {
    $flipped[$value][] = $key;
}
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/aA826

No it's not a function. But it's simple, why make it more complicated?

Comment: Exactly. This is the best way.

Comment: I was intrigued about that; turns out you don't get an error at all!

Comment: Because it's assignment. If I was trying to retrieve an array index that doesn't exist, I'd get undefined. Assignment works though.

Comment: @Thamilan yep! except we now have short array syntax, yay.

Comment: @jszobody I never downvote any answer.. I upvoted yours both first. I downvote only questions that are duplicates

Comment: I didn't want a custom code. Please delete your answer. I am going to delete this question. tnx.

Comment: @Mojtaba you shouldn't delete a question after answers have been received. You showed the result you needed, and two people here helped you get it.

Comment: @Thamilan my bad, was just the timing that made me think that.

Comment: @jszobody the surprising lack of error is that you can essentially do `$foo[] = 1` when `$foo` is undefined.

Comment: @jszobody, These 2 people didn't read my request carefully. It was easy for me to use a loop to create that. I asked in my question I am looking for a PHP function. Not a custom code.

Comment: If you just wanted the answer yes or no, couldn't you have read the documentation to determine that?

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with `array_reduce`:

```
$flipped = array_reduce(array_keys($arr), function ($carry, $item) use ($arr) {   
    $carry[$arr[$item]][] = $item;
    return $carry;
}, array());
```

Comment: I didn't want a custom code. Please delete your answer. I am going to delete this question. tnx.

Comment: @Mojtaba to be fair, this answer is using a predefined function to do exactly what you want. even if I think a loop is simpler, this answer is technically what you asked for. you should probably accept it.

Comment: @jszobody, Thanks. However, it's a custom code with a closure function.